# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaggle.competitions'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to download the data from kaggle competitions, but I have the problem of the title.
I've searched and I know that the problem is that I'm trying to run it for a kaggle kernel, not a local kernel, but I don´t know how to solve this.
I know that it is a stupid question, but I'm new on this and my teacher has told me to search here.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are getting this error when you try to run "Kaggle kernel" locally. According to the [Kaggle documentation](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/kernels) they are intended to run in the remote Kaggle environment:

> Kaggle Kernels run in a remote computational environment. We provide
>   the hardware—you need only worry about the code.

Remote Kaggle environment [differs](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/101) from their [public API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api), so it is not possible to run arbitrary Kaggle kernel locally. To run Kaggle kernel in Kaggle environment, you should:

1. Sign in on Kaggle site
2. Register for a competition
3. Go to "Kernels" tab on the competitions page
4. Press "New Kernel" button

Kaggle kernel will be opened in online editor, and you will be able to launch it remotely by pressing "Commit" button. Python module `kaggle.competitions` will be accessible from that environment.

For example, ongoing competition from [Two Sigma](https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news) accepts [only that data](https://www.kaggle.com/dster/two-sigma-news-official-getting-started-kernel/notebook), which is produced by Kaggle kernels. This allows them to provide data dynamically and don't expose it to programmer to avoid cheating. They use `twosigmanews` object from that non-public `kaggle.competitions` module for this dynamical interaction, so it is not possible to launch working code locally.